# What is GCP price list change impact on my upcoming invoice?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In case GCP changes prices during the month, how am I going to be charged: 
Based on the rate at the beginning of the month or according to the new rate?

Comment: This is definitely something you should ask support

Answer (score 0):

In the event of a price change on the products of Google Cloud Platform Products they usually make changes effectively since the 1st of the next month. In the event of changing the prices in the mid of a month the logical way is to be billed by the old rate for the usage prior to the day of change and with the new prices since the day of change.

The best option to clarify this kind of questions is to directly consult with the Billing team through [Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/) because each prices changes effects may for each customer.